# Bridge Edge Loops Problems

Tags: modeling

Just stuck with such a problem, I met this first time, before Bridge Edge Loop (BEL) function worked well. So when I try to BEL with two faces or edges and add number of cuts it goes like that, so before it didn't bulge to the side, it went smoother and as I note on third image.
Can't imagine what I did wrong...thanks for any tips!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing your blend file, but if you're doing pipework I would use the [spin tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MVmxTzbSrU).

Comment: THank you! I'm making a little tube from the coffee machine, so this tool may suit, but still can't understand why by making additional cuts they start to expand

Comment: As I said, we'd need you to upload the blend file [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/) to answer that one!

Comment: sorry, here it is

https://pasteall.org/blend/939166803a9341a988ebe157fbbe556b

Comment: The file you uploaded doesn't show any distortion here using the same blender version as you although the bend on the pipe does have a few minor glitches on the bend. How did you create the bend?

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure why it happens, but it looks as if you were going via the Edge > Bridge Edge Loops menu which does indeed produce the odd distortion you're seeing. I've only ever used Blender's built-in LoopTools addon which you can enable by searching for 'loop' under Edit > Preferences > Addons and then access via the Right-click > LoopTools > Bridge menu which is why I couldn't produce your problem. That still doesn't explain why your own file looks fine when I open it here though...

Comment: Well, after attempts to do a tube in the original way, trying to click and change any functions (didn't help) I decided to rotate two cylinders 45 degrees to each other and it worked. 
But for example today also tried to figure out this function, and switching to Blend Path in Edge Loop Setting helped, but before that it didn't worked as well....so can't understand what was the exact reason...
But still thank you very much for tips! That'so helpful! :)